# In Highcharts, if there's range or setExtremes, when scroll x-axis the values of label (tickPositioner) disappear

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a strange problem...

my chart is date time, zoomable (but i removed option to zoom it). My data are values of week (start of week), i have a tickpositioner because i want that xAxis ticks are in the same place as points

I have also range (i tried also setExtremes)...

The problem is a scrollbar (and for me is important):

when the page is ready is all ok, but if i scroll, values of label x-axis disappear :(

Why ?

this jsfiddle

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/xwvs3cfw/`
```

I hope that you can help me, sorry for my english... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case when you define a tick array, you can use tickPositions. Next step is use min/max value instead of range.

```
 xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPositions: array2,
        min:Date.UTC(2013, 5, 14),
        max: Date.UTC(2013, 6, 19),
        labels: {
            format: '{value: %d/%m/%y}',
            rotation: 0,
            align: 'left'
            // enabled: true
        },

    },
```

Fixed demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xwvs3cfw/2/

Comment: but than the problem is that the scrollbar.... is possible to set position of scrollbar ?

Comment: Do you mean different range on scrollbar or something different?

Comment: exact, I mean the range of the scrollbar (set it to the last four ticks)

Comment: So set different min/max values on xAxis.